# How to programmatically do math operations on two fields of type "Time" in Infopath

Tags: c#, datetime, infopath2010

I have an issue here that hopefully someone can help me out with.

I have created a time card in `infopath` and would like to have some calculations perform automatically based on values entered by the user. I had originally done this using a combination of rules, unfortunately I got hit with the "infinite loop" warning once the form was in `SharePoint`, because it performed more than 16 calculations.

So, I decided to switch to `c#` to make the calculations a lot easier. However, I am not sure how to actually perform the parsing of the time field into a datetime variable, and googling hasn't been much of a friend in this case, as everyone is offering "no code" solutions.

I was able to find [this](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/browserforms/calculate-date-difference-infopath-browser-form-c-sharp-code.htm) example, which is *close* to what I want, except they seem to be going for a date field using `DateTime.ParseExact()`.

I made my form convert the value of a time field into a string just to test the value to see what I get. I used `8:01 AM` for example and got the following as the string value: `"08:01:00-08:00"`.

I get that the first part of the value is representing 8:01 and no milliseconds, I'm not even sure what the part after the dash is supposed to signify though?

Does anyone know how I might convert that to a `datetime` variable in `C#`, so that I might be able to do some calculations on it? Any help here would be HUGELY appreciated. Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: what is your exact date field looks like i.e. in which format it is, is it full date or time only

Comment: The fields I want to do the calculations on are time only.

Comment: You never explain what format your Time is in. What does the string look like?

Comment: Also, the 2nd part after the dash is likely a timezone

Answer (score 0):

As you stated that the strings are in Time format, rather trying to format them to `DateTime` we can use `TimeSpan`,

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] dateValues = { "08:01 AM", "08:01 PM" };
    string[] pattern = new string[] { @"hh\:mm\ \A\M", @"hh\:mm\ \P\M" };

    DateTime parsedDate;
    TimeSpan interval = new TimeSpan();
    foreach (string dateValue in dateValues)
    {
        if (TimeSpan.TryParseExact(dateValue, pattern, null, out interval))
            Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", dateValue, interval.ToString("c"));
        else
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to parse '{0}'", dateValue);
    }
}
```

May be this can help you to approach your problem a little differently.

**Since you are talking about calculations**, I believe you would need time in 24 hours format so you can tweak the code and check if the `TimeSpan` is parsed by **`PM`** format and then you can perform your calculation based on that.

You can refer [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee372287%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for more and detailed information.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was trying to test out this, but the Visual Studio Tools for Applications that InfoPath 2010 uses, does not have a few of these things (unless there is a reference I need to add?). No support for var (I just substituted string instead), but TimeSpan does not have a definition for TryParseExact() or allow for the ToString method to specify the character like you're doing in interval.ToString("C"). This is getting me thinking of things in a different way though... I honestly hadn't encountered TimeSpan before.

Comment: you can use `string` in place of `var`

Comment: Yeah I did do that. Ok, so my thought here is actually to grab the field value, use Substring(0, shiftStart.IndexOf("-") so I only grab the relevant time portion to create a dateTime object, which I append a arbitrary date to (DateTime TrueShiftStart = DateTime.Parse(shiftstartpart, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);) then, use TimeSpan to grab all the math involved. I think you have definitely put me on the right path here though. Thoughts? Am I doing that inefficiently?

Comment: I should mention I am not a programmer by trade, so if I am going about this stupidly, I would definitely appreciate the feedback. I'm just trying to work within the framework MS provided in visual studio tools for applications.